# Spindle moulder blocks and cutters

Tags: joinery, router, power-tools, cutting, router-table

I have just purchased an old Tyzack spindle moulder (shaper) and need some help please.

I'm new to carpentry and have never used a spindle moulder before. I am in need of a block and cutters. I believe the Bore size is 22mm but most blocks I’ve come across are 30mm (as far as I can tell).

Is there a way of changing the machine to take 30mm or can you point me in the right direction for acquiring a 22mm bore block.

I'm living in the UK, if that helps.

Here are some images of the machine, I have also posted the plates but it doesn’t really give much info.

Thanks,
Josh
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]
[image: image 4]

Comment: Welcome to Woodworking:SE.  I'm afraid "shopping" questions are not on-topic here.  I suggest contacting Axminster or Trend (or if you are in Cambridge, ask at Mackays).

Comment: @MartinBonner  This does not appear to be a shopping question.

Comment: I agree. It does ask about finding 22mm blocks, but is a general question about "how to make this old tool go" which is sort of the _raison d'etre_ of WW.SE.

Comment: OP, you should maybe share the model info, as I know many people here have Old Tools Info and Manual Sites bookmarked, and at least we can point you in the right direction. Because I think you want specific information for this tool, at least for safety reasons.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it’s not meant to be a shopping question I was hoping for some help on the bite size and possibility of changing it. I don’t have a model number but would a image be suffice?

Comment: You can [edit] the question at any time and clarify it based on comments. Ideally you have a model number or other identifying info. Try to be as specific as possible.

Comment: By the way, someone has retained the name "Tyzack" and is selling woodworking tools from a storefront in Shoreditch. Might be worth dropping them a line and asking if they can point you in the right direction, assuming they are somewhat related to the historical Tyzacks traditionally based in and around Hackney https://www.tyzacktools.com/contactus.aspx

Comment: @jdv thank you, I wasn’t aware of that. I will give them a call and see if they can give me any more info.

Comment: Oh, it occurs to me that it is unlikely that anything on this vintage of machinery is sized in metric. I know that some stuff you can just size to the millimetre and get away with it, but be sure.

Comment: Hi Bush block down to 22 mm you just need some one with metal lathe or make new spindle

Comment: Hi Joshua, I don't think you'll get enough on-point info on this here to make it worth anyone trying to provide an Answer. There's a wealth of experience on old machines like this on the UK woodworking forums so I'd suggest asking on one of those. **Edit:** wanted to add, in case you don't know these are extraordinarily dangerous machines to use, so take great care if you get it up and running!!

Comment: If you can't find the proper sized shafts, you might talk to a local, _reputable_ machine shop. They may be able to make an adapter for you that will chuck into the spindle you have and accept the spindle sizes that are currently available.  I say "reputable" because you're going to have large, heavy, sharp hunks of metal spinning at arm removing speeds if it's not done well. "Reputable" as in, not afraid to say, "you're nuts for even thinking that", as opposed to "we'll do whatever the customer wants, so long as we get paid".